# how to get id from .html() in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

following is my code i want to access "course-type" id from .htm() method how to access that id

```
 $("#question-type").html("<option>Select</option><option>Excel Sheet</option><option>One by One</option>");

$("#question-type").change(function(){
    $("#course").html("<label>Select course </label><select id='course-type'><option>Course 1</option><option>Course 2</option><option>Course 3</option></select>");
});

$("#course-type").change(function(){

    $("#subject").html("<label>Select subject </label><select id='subject-type'><option>Subject 1</option><option>Subject 2</option><option>Subject 3</option></select>");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it hasn't been added to the DOM yet then it won't be able to be accessed. Since it won't be created until `#question-type`'s change function is executed, you may be trying to access it before it exists.

Answer (score 3):

Try This.

When you are adding course-type select list on DOM, create change event handler that time.

```
$("#question-type").change(function(){
    $("#course").html("<label>Select course </label><select id='course-type'><option>Course 1</option><option>Course 2</option><option>Course 3</option></select>");
    $("#course-type").change(function(){
          $("#subject").html("<label>Select subject </label><select id='subject-type'><option>Subject 1</option><option>Subject 2</option><option>Subject 3</option></select>");
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks lot yograj....if i want to use that id out side function which is declared in .html() for example if i write ajax and i want to use "course-type" id then how can i use that id

Answer (score 1):

To bind handlers to events for elements not yet in the DOM, use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$("#course").on("change", "#course-type", function(){
    $("#subject").html("<label>Select subject </label><select id='subject-type'><option>Subject 1</option><option>Subject 2</option><option>Subject 3</option></select>");
});
```

Using this method has the advantage of not rebinding to the event every time the `question-type` changes; you bind a single handler to the parent element (`#course`) and wait for the change event to bubble up from the `#course-type` element, if it exists.